# Java Integer.parseInt failed to parse a string

Tags: java

I'm parsing a string of 15 digits like this:

```
String str = "100004159312045";
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

I'm getting an exception when doing so.
Why? What are the limitations for `Integer.parseInt`? What other options do I have for converting such long string to a number?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your number is too large to fit in an `int` which is 32 bits and only has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Try [`Long.parseLong`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) instead. A `long` has 64 bits and has a range of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 5):

because int's maximum value is a little above 2,000,000,000

you can use long or BigInteger

long has double the digits it can store (the max value is square that of int) and BigInteger can handle arbitrarily large numbers

Answer (score 4):

int is 32 signed bit, its max value is 2^31-1 = 2147483647

Answer (score 3):

The value you are trying to parse exceeds the maximum size of an Integer.

Answer (score 3):

The range of `int` is between `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` inclusive (i.e. from 2147483647 down to -2147483648).  You cannot parse the `int` value of out that range.

You can use `long m = Long.parseLong(str);` or `BigInteger b = new BigInteger(str);` for large integer.