# ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

Tags: java, parsing, sonarqube, numberformatexception

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9223372036854775808"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Comment: Do you really mean that this is enough to get help?

Comment: What else should i add?

Comment: @ToheedAhsanButt Your question suggests some correlation with Sonar, but you don't explain what you were trying to achieve and what your actions caused the error.

Comment: The current state of your question make it impossible to answer because the stacktrace is way too short to determine where the issue might be happening: please precise what you are trying to do and provide a complete stacktrace.
And, obviously : What is your question ?

Comment: oh and obviously version of the java plugin of Sonarqube and version of sonarqube would help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an overflow error:

```
Max long value: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
Your string:    9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

Note: it seems that in `Java` discriminating between invalid format and overflow is not trivial, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451066/how-to-detect-overflow-when-convert-string-to-integer-in-java).